# How many database instance can Azure Cosmos DB support per subcription/account

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Cosmos DB as my database. Just wondering how many database instance I can create under my Azure account? It is saying that the starting instance number is 200 per account. I may need around 1000 database instance per my tenant.

Thanks advanced.

Comment: 1000 databases? Or 1000 *collections*? Note: Each collection can scale considerably, and a single database may have many collections. Probably best to open a billing support ticket to have your quota increased. Nothing can be done here...

Comment: Thanks Davide. I know each database can have many collections, might with no limitation. Each collection can scale too. Maybe just run a provision to create several thousands of database in one subscription to see whether Azure allows me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [feeback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6395963-increase-limit-beyond-100-databases-per-account) about the limitation of total databases number per Cosmos DB account. Also, I checked this issue on my side, and this limitation for 100 databases per Cosmos DB account still remains. For Azure Cosmos DB account number limit per subscription, I checked [DocumentDB limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#documentdb-limits), but find nothing useful information. I have 20+ Cosmos DB account under my subscription. I assumed that you could send email to askdocdb@microsoft.com for more details about limitation of Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: Thank you Bruce! Will send them an email asking the details.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the [Azure Cosmos DB service quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#per-account-limits) documentation states that you can have **unlimited** number of databases per account, so if there has been any limitations before they seem to be lifted. Just beware, it can get costly.